# What is the difference between 因为 and 应为?

Tags: meaning, usage, difference

They are pronounced similarly and are both translated into "because". What is the difference in their meaning? When should I use one over the other?

Comment: There is no such thing as **应为**, which seems like a typo or a spelling error. There is only **因为**.

Comment: Where did you find 应为 defined as »because«?

Comment: Welcome to Chinese Language SE. Can you add the link to your question? Or edit it to include full sentence?

Answer (score 6):

"应为" does not mean "because". If it is used as because, then it is an error, maybe a typo.

"应为" used together, it is usually two separate words, and can mean "should(应) be(为)".

Answer (score 1):

We can break down the expression into individual characters:

- 「因」means *reason*;
- 「爲」(为), in this context, means *to be*.

In contrast, 「應」(应) means *should*.

- 「因爲」is *reason + be* = *because*
- 「應爲」can be seen as a shortening of **應該爲** (*should* + *be*)

---

Also, note that「因」is pronounced **yīn**, while「應」is pronounced **yīng**.

Answer (score 0):

应为 for "because" is a typo. It's not in 汉语大词典，for example.